# Find common words in sentences with Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a task to find words that are in each sentence.

Given a string and we want to divide the string into sentences and then determine which words, if any, are in all the sentences.

Here is my solution:

```
# encoding: utf-8
text = ''
File.foreach("lab2.in") do |line|
    text += line
end
hash = Hash.new
text = text.gsub(/[\n,]/,'').split(/[!.?]/)
number = 0
text.each do |sen|
        number += 1
        words = sen.split(/ /)
        words.each do |word|
                if hash[word]
                        hash[word] += "#{number}"
                else
                        hash[word] = "#{number}"
                end
        end
end
flag = false
needle = ''
count = text.length
for i in 1..count
        needle += "#{i}"
end
hash.each do |word|
        if word[1].squeeze == needle
                puts "this word is \"#{word[0]}\""
                flag = true
        end
end
if !flag
        puts "There no such word"
end
```

How this task can be solved maybe more prettily? I'm interested in Ruby library methods. A simple solution, like character-by-character cycle I already know.

For example, with input like:

```
lorem ipsum dolor and another lorem! sit amet lorem? and another lorem.
```

The output will be:

```
this word is "lorem"
```

Comment: What is expected input and output?

Comment: For example input like: lorem ipsum lorem dolor sit amet. a tut toje est lorem!
i tuta toje lorem?

Comment: And output will be this word is "lorem"

Comment: Please add your expected input and output to your question, not to comments. That helps people answering you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do this (I modified your example slightly):

```
str = "a lorem ipsum lorem dolor sit amet. a tut toje est lorem! a i tuta toje lorem?"  

 str.split(/[.!?]/).map(&:split).reduce(:&)
  #=> ["a", "lorem"]
```

We have:

```
d = str.split(/[.!?]/)
  #=> ["a lorem ipsum lorem dolor sit amet",
  #    " a tut toje est lorem",
  #    " a i tuta toje lorem"] 
e = d.map(&:split)
  #=> [["a", "lorem", "ipsum", "lorem", "dolor", "sit", "amet"],
  #    ["a", "tut", "toje", "est", "lorem"],
  #    ["a", "i", "tuta", "toje", "lorem"]] 
e.reduce(:&)
  #=> ["a", "lorem"]
```

To make it case-insensitive, change `str.split...` to `str.downcase.split...`.

Comment: This great, thank you. But can you explain what means &:split ?

Comment: `d.map(&:split)` gives the same result as `d.map { |a| s.split }`; it converts each string `s` in `d` to an array of words contained in `s`. If those arrays (in `e`) are `a1`, `a2` and `a3`, `e.reduce { |a,b| b & a }` is equivalent to `a1 & a2 & a3`.

Comment: While in this example `[.!?]` works, I'd recommend using the POSIX `[[:punct:]]` class instead because it contains all punctuation.

Comment: @theTinMan `[[:punct:]]` will match commas, so it wouldn't fit the requirement of splitting on sentences.

Comment: That's true, the OP was stripping commas.

Comment: @skad0 I suggest taking some time to understand how to use both`reduce` and the binary `&` operator when used on arrays (if you don't understand already). They are a large part of what makes this solution so short & elegant.